# dependent filtering with two jquery dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, leaflet

I have two drop-down menus. One dropdown (containing quantitative variables) decides the size of the circles and the other dropdown (containing categorical variables) which decides the colour of the circle created on leaflet map. When I select sizing variable I want the color variable to be fixed to the variable he chooses earlier. "sizedropdown" and "colordropdown" contains the name of the variables while sizeExtents containes the min and max value of quantative variables and colorextent contains the unique categories.

```
var dropDown_size = d3.select("#sizeSection")
    .selectAll("option").data(sizedropDown)
    .enter().append("option")
    .text(function(d) {return d ;} )
    .attr("value", function(d,i) { return i;} );

var dropDown_color = d3.select("#colorSection")
    .selectAll("option").data(colordropDown)
    .enter().append("option")
    .text(function(d) { return d;} )
    .attr("value", function(d,i) {return i;} );

d3.select('#sizeSection')
  .on("change", function () {
      var section_color = 0;
      var sect_size = document.getElementById("sizeSection");
      var section_size = sect_size.options[sect_size.selectedIndex].value;
      updateSubset(all_data.features,section_size,section_color);
  });

d3.select('#colorSection')
  .on("change", function () {
      var section_size = 0;
      var sect_color = document.getElementById("colorSection");
      var section_color = sect_color.options[sect_color.selectedIndex].value;
      updateSubset(all_data.features,section_size,section_color);
  });
```

My updateSubset function works on the map. The update subset functions looks like:

```
function updateSubset(subset,section_size,section_color) {

    var size_name = sizedropDown[section_size];
    var size_extent = sizeExtents[section_size];
    var sizeScale = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .domain(size_extent)
        .range([5,15]);

    var color_name = colordropDown[section_color]
    var color_extent = colorExtents[section_color];
    var c10 = function(d){
        var colors = ["#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099",
                      "#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00", "#b82e2e", "#316395",
                      "#994499", "#22aa99", "#aaaa11", "#6633cc", "#e67300",
                      "#8b0707", "#651067", "#329262", "#5574a6", "#3b3eac"];
        return  colors.slice(0,d)};
    var ordinalScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(color_extent)
        .range(c10(color_extent.length));

    var bounds = path.bounds({
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: subset
    });
    var topLeft = bounds[0];
    var bottomRight = bounds[1];
    var arc = d3.svg.symbol().type('circle');

    svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
       .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
       .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
       .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

    var points = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(subset,function(d){return d.geometry.coordinates;});

    points.enter().append("path");
    points.attr("d", path).attr("class", "points");
    points.attr("d",path.pointRadius(function(d) {
        return sizeScale(d.properties[size_name]);})
    );
    points.style("fill-opacity", 0.4);
    points.style("fill", function(d){
        return ordinalScale(d.properties[color_name]);}
    );
}
```

I could not understand how to store the choice of one filter when the other is changing.

Comment: why don't you make the variables `var section_color = 0; var section_size = 0;` global, change there value inside the `change` callback and call the `update` function

Comment: why are you changing the `d` attribute of the `path` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem, but I think the easiest is to store the current values in a variable that both the select element change listeners and any code that needs it (e.g. `updateSubset`) can access. Here is a simple example:

```js
// all functions in this script can access `current`
var current = {
  colour: 'schemeBlues',
  size: '30'
}

// when the select element changes, set the current value of `this.name`
// (i.e. either current.colour or current.size) to `this.value`
// `this` is the element that triggered the event
function changeListener () {
  current[ this.name ] = this.value

  // print out current values
  d3.select('#result')
    .append('p')
    .text('Colour: ' + current.colour + '; size: ' + current.size)
}

// add a select element with `arr` as the option items and `name` as 
// the select element id and name
function addCntrl ( arr, name ) {
  // add a select element
  var cntrl = d3.select('#controls')
    .append('select')
    .attr('name', name )
    .attr('id', name )

  cntrl.selectAll('option')
  .data( arr )
    .enter()
    .append( 'option' )
    .attr('value', d => d.value )
    .text( d => d.name )

  // set the selected value to current[name] (i.e. current.colour or current.size)
  cntrl.property('value', current[name])

  cntrl.on('change', changeListener)
}

function init() {
  var colours = Object.keys(d3)
      .filter( function(c){ return (c.indexOf('scheme') !== -1) })
      .map( function(c) {
          return {
            value: c,
            name: c.replace('scheme','')
                   .replace(/(\D)(\d)/, '$1 $2')
          }
        } ),
  sizes = [ '10', '20', '30', '40', '50' ].map( e => { return { value: e, name: e } } )

  // add select elements to the page
  addCntrl(colours, 'colour')
  addCntrl(sizes, 'size')
  
}


init()
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<div id="controls"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I don't know how your whole script looks, but you could do something similar:

```
var current = {
  color: 'blue',
  size: 'super_massive'
}

function updateSubset( subset ) {
  var section_size = current.size,
  section_color = current.color
  [ ... ]

}

function selectChanged() {
  current[this.name] = this.value;
  updateSubset( all_data.features )
}

[ ... ]

// make sure that both select elements have their `name` attribute set, then:
d3.select('#sizeSection')
  .on('change', selectChanged)
d3.select('#colorSection')
  .on('change', selectChanged)

[ ... ]
```

or you can also pass in `current` if you want to control the scope more tightly:

```
function updateSubset( subset, opts ) {
  var section_size = opts.size,
  section_color = opts.color
  [ ... ]

}

[ ... ]

function selectChanged() {
  current[this.name] = this.value;
  updateSubset( all_data.features, current )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The way you explained was awesome.